# How to find records in SOQL where the email address has non alpha numeric characters before the @ sign?

Tags: data

I want to find records using either SOQL or Apex where the email address has non alpha numeric characters before the @ sign. I am new to regex and SOQL.

Comment: Apex - no regex needed. You can use `substringBefore` and `isAlphaNumeric` methods in the [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class. It's worth noting that valid email addresses [can contain non-alphanumeric chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844431/are-email-addresses-allowed-to-contain-non-alphanumeric-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the email address field is not Shield encrypted, add a Checkbox Formula field to the object

```
Is_AlphaNumeric_Email__c
```

The formula needs to extract the string before the `@` (Use the FIND and LEFT functions) and then apply a regex on the substring. I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

You can find regex patterns for testing the alphanumeric-ness of the substring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988258/3034170)

and then query

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM MyObject WHERE Is_NonAlphaNumeric_Email__c = false
```

Notes:

If you have a huge number of records, you may need to add an additional filter on an indexed field as the query will do a table scan